# Como puedo sobrescribir un archivo json en unity 3d?

Tags: c#, array, json, unity3d

mi problema es que no puedo o no encuentro la manera de sobrescribir el archivo json en unity, necesito hacer esto cada segundo ya que las variables dentro del json deben ir variando.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerConstantMove : MonoBehaviour
{
gameManager GameManager;
private Animator animator;
public TextAsset jsonData;
public PlayerList players = new PlayerList();
public float Speed;

[System.Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public float CoordenadaY;
    public float CoordenadaX;
    public string ID;
    public float Velocidad;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerList
{
    public Player[] player;
}

void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    GameObject gameController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController");
    GameManager = gameController.GetComponent<gameManager>();
    players = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerList>(jsonData.text);
    Debug.Log("Velocidad =" + players.player[0].Velocidad);
    Speed = players.player[0].Velocidad;
}


void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(GameManager.moveVector * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Speed);
}
}
```

Estaba pensando en hacer un código en la parte de void update(), pero no tengo claro que hacer.
Cualquier ayuda respecto al tema agradecido de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estas en Unity, transformas tu objeto Json en una clase. Luego cuando lo tengas que enviar al servidor lo parseas a json otra vez.

```
players = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerList>(jsonData.text);
players[0].Velocidad= 1f;
string nuevoJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(players);
```

- Si puedes hacerlo en update, puedes enviar la informacion

Estas trabajando con sockets?
Y igual aun no entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer.